# How to set SearchLookUpEdit for DevExpress ComboboxEdit in UserControl from Container control?

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, data-binding, user-controls, devexpress

I have a UserControl that contains DevExpress ComboBoxEdit control with SearchLookUpEdit as an editor set. I have set searchLookUpEditView, and its columns in Designer also.

I want to set UserControl's DataSource, DisplayMember and ValueMember attributes from the container control, but in the runtime i get the error

```
"Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery) is not supported. Instead populate a DbSet with data, for example by calling Load on the DbSet, and then bind to local data"
```

but if i use this code, to set DataSource for ComboboxEdit that is in the container, not in the UserControl - then everything works fine

#### The code from the parent control:

```
    //_context is Entity Framework's ObjectContext
    //workUnit1 is UserControl, that contains ComboBoxEdit control
        var mod3 = (from a in _context.Darbi
                    select new { a.ID, a.pieteikuma_Nr, a.Nosaukums, title = a.pieteikuma_Nr + " " + a.Nosaukums });

        workUnit1.DataSource = mod3;
        workUnit1.ValueMember = "ID";
        workUnit1.DisplayMember = "title";
```

#### The code from the UserControl:

```
    [ComplexBindingProperties("DataSource", "DisplayMember")] //UserControl's attributes
    public partial class WorkUnit: UserControl
    {
        //DataBinding parameters from container control
        private object _dSource; //dataSource
        private string _dMember; //displayMember
        private string _vMember; //valueMember

        //..//

        [AttributeProvider(typeof(IListSource))]
        public object DataSource
        {
            get { return _dSource; }
            set
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    _dSource = value;

                //workNameCmbBox is ComboBoxEdit control that i need to set SearchLookUpEdit from parent control
                    workNameCmbBox.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", _dSource, "ID");//The error is thrown at this line...
                 }
            }
            public string DisplayMember
            {
                get { return _dMember; }
                set
                {
                    _dMember = value ?? "";//ja null, tad ""
                    workNameCmbBox.Properties.DisplayMember = _dMember;
                } 
            }
            public string ValueMember
            {
                get { return _vMember; }
                set { 
                _vMember = value ?? ""; //ja null, tad ""
                workNameCmbBox.Properties.ValueMember = _vMember;
                }
            }
        }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind directly to the query results, but need to populate some local collection instead. To accomplish this task you can use the following code:

```
var list = mod3.ToList();
workUnit1.DataSource = list;
```

or even the following code:

**EDIT**

```
BindingList<T> bList = new BindingList<T>();

//
//...populate bList
//

BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
bSource.DataSource = bList;

//...set DataSource for usercontrol
workUnit1.DataSource = bSource;
```

Comment: Thank's a lot! Maybe you can explain the difference between those two options?

Comment: The difference is that the second option provides the `IBindingList` instance which more powerfull for binding purposes (supports changing notifications) than `IList` (first option)

Comment: For IBindingList example i get NotSupportedException error: Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery) is not supported. Instead populate a DbSet with data, for example by calling Load on the DbSet, and then bind to local data. For WPF bind to DbSet.Local. For WinForms bind to DbSet.Local.ToBindingList()